# jsp jstl sql query tag using declared variables?

Tags: mysql, jstl

Having an issue using "SET @" anything within jstl.  Is there a trick to gettikng it to work?

```
<sql:query var="weektots" dataSource="jdbc/x" >
SET @tot:=0;
SELECT
 (@tot := @tot + 5) AS rt
<sql:query>
```

Other attempts that do not work:

```
<sql:transaction dataSource="jdbc/x">
<sql:query var="weektots" >
    SET @tot:=0;
 <sql:query>
 <sql:query var="weektots" dataSource="jdbc/x" >
       SELECT
     (@tot := @tot + 5) AS rt
    <sql:query>
  </sql:transaction>
```

and

```
  <c:set var="tot" value="0" />
  <sql:query var="weektots" dataSource="jdbc/x">
       SELECT
     (${tot} := ${tot} + 5) AS rt
  <sql:query>
```

Any way to acocmplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up creating a stored procedure to execute this within JSTL.

```
    DELIMITER $$
 CREATE PROCEDURE w10rt()
   BEGIN
    SET @tot:=0;
    SELECT
     (@tot := @tot + 5) AS rt
   END $$
 DELIMITER ;
```

Use "Call w10rt" within the jsp get results correctly.

```
  Call w10rt
```